# How to set equal spacing with Android GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

How to set the space left over to be divided equally?

For example, I have a GridView with 2 columns. The full width is 700px, and the column is 200px: how do I specify the xml, so the space left (300px) are divided evenly into 3 pieces?

i.e. 100px | 200px (Column 1) | 100px | 200px (Column 2) | 100px

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the `android:stretchMode` to `spacingWidthUniform`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode

Comment: May seem obvious (it wasn't to me), but you need to remove any `android:horizontalSpacing` you have otherwise it will not work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` as such

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout app:columnCount="5">
    <Space app:layout_columnWeight="1> 
    <View>
    <Space app:layout_columnWeight="1"/> 
    <View>
    <Space app:layout_columnWeight="1>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

to achieve the desired effect, unless you are building exclusively for SDK 21, and then use the normal GridLayout